# lhttpc client error

Tags: erlang

I tried lhttpc client and got strange error:

```
7> lhttpc:request("https://money.yandex.ru",head,[],infinity).
{ok,{{200,"OK"},
 [{"Server","lighttpd/1.4.26"},
  {"Date","Fri, 02 Sep 2011 20:29:02 GMT"},
  {"Expires","Fri, 02 Sep 2011 20:29:02 GMT"},
  {"Content-Type","text/html; charset=windows-1251"},
  {"Cache-Control","max-age=0, proxy-revalidate"}],
 <<>>}}
8> lhttpc:request("https://money.yandex.ru",get,[],infinity). 
** exception exit: {{case_clause,{ok,<<"\r\n">>}},
                [{lhttpc_client,read_trailers,4},
                 {lhttpc_client,read_chunked_body,4},
                 {lhttpc_client,handle_response_body,4},
                 {lhttpc_client,read_response,4},
                 {lhttpc_client,execute,9},
                 {lhttpc_client,request,9}]}
 in function  lhttpc:request/9
```

As you can see I firstly tried to perform a HEAD request and it went ok, and then I made a GET request and it failed. Did anyone come across this bug and maybe somebody do know how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of lhttpc are you running?

Comment: Ummm... I don't know really. I just clone two versions of it from esl and oscarh git repositaries. Both gave me the same error.

Comment: I suppose it's 1.2.6. But I can't find the place where it's stated exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. It seems that it's not the error of lhttpc library but Erlang itself.

It seems that sometimes `erlang:decode_packet` function does not return `http_eoh` when it should.

I use R14B04 Erlang cloned from their git repository, may be that was a reason. I've no time to dig it deeper so I patched lhttpc itself.

Comment: If you've got a sample packet that triggers this fault I think the [erlang-bugs](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs) mailing list would be happy to look at it!

Comment: Also, if you used the stable R14B03 tag it should be the same version that is downloadable on the Erlang web page.